# A good drawing library for Java that uses Jogl (and it is not Java2D)

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I was wondering if there is a rasterization library (like Cairo is for C) written in Java, that uses Jogl as it's backend.

Answer (score 0):

[GLG2D](https://github.com/brandonborkholder/glg2d) does pretty much what you want.  You can draw using the Java2D API, specifically Graphics2D, and the rendering is done with OpenGL.

Alternatively, just use JOGL if you have the opportunity to build the application from scratch.